# Jquery Ajax call returns data but success function not called due to jquery function [jQuery111208562382296659052_1443009765276 function] not called?

Tags: jquery, ajax

While executing ajax call its return JSON data but success function not called. My ajax function code as below:

```
var lsUrl= "my service api address";
$.ajax({
    url: lsUrl,
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",  // from the server   
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // to the server        
    ProcessData: true,
    success: function (success) {//my success operation  code }error:function(error){}});


//**In above code the service api link returns json data.i got json data properly but its not return to success function.i get following error :**
```

200 parsererror  jQuery111209869910120032728_1443011402050 was not called.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: if you uncomment out the error routine is it called?  how do you know json is being returned?

Comment: Is your request _actually_ `jsonp` like you're specifying?

Answer (score 0):

Use application/javascript as content type.

```
contentType: "application/javascript; charset=utf-8"
```

Comment: issue not fixed after changed contentType: "application/javascript; charset=utf-8".@batra

Comment: Please chek your API is able ot support CORS or Not if it is able to support ,then not need to use json p. And what is the objective of using jason p ?

Comment: if your API is sending data in json format. Then change teh data type into application/Json and in success parse your message with JSON.parse(apiOutput). it will convert it to javascript object then you can easily go through that.

Comment: Actually i get data from server side.After that data handled in jquery.min.js like  jQuery[dynamic generated id] function ({my json value}).my pblm is  jQuery[dynamic generated id] function ["this function generated by jquery.js script dynamically"]not generated so ajax request refuse the return data as not in json format.

Comment: How you are saying data is handled in jquery.min.js means success of ajax is hitting ?

Comment: My API Service returns Data like :


jQuery111205524142505601048_1443178060859({"d":"{\"Table\":[{\"column1\":14}]}"});

Comment: If I am not wrong once you set json as data type then servce is returning without jQuery111205524142505601048_1443178060859 ?

Comment: Then this is not a problem it is a solution. Let the dataType be json and in success your response is actually in success.d.yourObject here you will have to iterate through hope it will solve your problem